# How to get data from a spotify palylist

Tags: json, api, spotify

I am trying to get information about a playlist in spotify.
I saw that the API requires a playlist_id

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}
```

Does anyone know where i can get that from.

Or any other solution to how to get data from spotify from the API.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single Spotify Playlist in mind, you can find the Playlist ID in:

- the URL bar for the playlist on open.spotify.com
- in Spotify if you navigate to the playlist, then go to Playlist Options (...) > Share > Playlist Link or the Spotify URI

If you don't want a specific Playlist, the API also provides methods for getting Playlists in bulk for a User or Search, and you can acquire Playlist IDs that way too